# Savefig do not correctly save the displayed plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, save

I plot a figure full screen and want to save it in .png with savefig. The result is an image much smaller than the plotted figure. And it is not a matter of dpi (the global figure is smaller but the fonts and linewidth are at the right size, so if I increase the dpi, the font increases too much).
Here is a very simple example so you can reproduce it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.sin(3*x)
y3 = np.sin(5*x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
figManager.window.showMaximized()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.09, top=0.96, right=0.97, left=0.07)

plt.plot(x,y1, 'C0', linewidth = 2)
plt.plot(x,y2, 'C1', linewidth = 2)
plt.plot(x,y3, 'C2', linewidth = 2)

plt.xlabel('x label', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('y label', fontsize=18)
plt.xticks(color='k', size=16)
plt.yticks(color='k', size=16)
plt.grid()
plt.legend(['blue', 'red', 'green'], fontsize=16)

fig.savefig('coco_gcf-dpi.png', dpi=plt.gcf().dpi, bbox_inches = 'tight')
fig.savefig('coco_200dpi.png', dpi=200, bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.show()
```

You can see that the plots saved are different from the plot displayed on your screen. And increasing the dpi does not help.

I should also specify that I am using Python 3.6 and Spyder 3.2.8 with Qt5 backend.
If anyone manages to change this code so the displayed figure is correctly saved (same overall size, same font size, same line thickness), I would be very grateful!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. For me the figure is correctly saved with (in my case) 19.2x9.44 inches (because I have 1920x1080 pixel screen resolution). The exact numbers may differ due to the window's border, taskbar etc.

Comment: That is interesting. What graphical backend are you using? Also, did you execute the program all at once or part by part? It may sound weird but if I first execute the plotting part, then type the savefig part in the console, it works well. But when I execute the program all at once it doesn't... (the saved plots are small, as they were before being enlarged to fullscreen)

Comment: The code will only work with Qt backend (in all other backends there is no `showMaximized()`, hence it would produce an error). I executed the script all at once (pressing F5 in Spyder).

Comment: Humm, no idea what the difference is with me. In my case, it looks like 'showMaximized()' is only applied for display but not when I save the figure. Anyway, I found a way to replace it and it works now! See my second post with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The last few lines of your script should look like:

```
plt.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('coco_gcf-dpi.png', dpi=plt.gcf().dpi)
fig.savefig('coco_200dpi.png', dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

Using `plt.tight_layout` makes the tight layout work for both the saved and interactively displayed figures. They way you originally had it, tight layout was only applied to the saved figures.

Comment: Note that `tight_layout` is completely different from setting the `bbox_inches = 'tight'` option. They are not at all related.

Comment: I cannot use tight_layout because I have some complicated figures (with 60 subplots or so) and tight_layout messes everything up. That is why I use plt.subplots_adjust (which actually works well for the displayed figures).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `showMaximized()` was only applied to the displayed figure and not to the saved one, so the only solution I found is to get rid of `showMaximized()`, find the size of the screen with tkinter, and use these dimensions to specify the size of the figure:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
```

returns the height and width of the screen in pixels

```
mydpi = 100
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(width/mydpi, height/mydpi), dpi=mydpi)
```

sets the dpi of the figure and uses the dimensions found previously to set the size of the figure as full screen.

Finally, the full code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()

mydpi = 100
x = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.sin(3*x)
y3 = np.sin(5*x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(width/mydpi, height/mydpi), dpi=mydpi)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.09, top=0.96, right=0.97, left=0.07)

plt.plot(x,y1, 'C0', linewidth = 2)
plt.plot(x,y2, 'C1', linewidth = 2)
plt.plot(x,y3, 'C2', linewidth = 2)

plt.xlabel('x label', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('y label', fontsize=18)
plt.xticks(color='k', size=16)
plt.yticks(color='k', size=16)
plt.grid()
plt.legend(['blue', 'red', 'green'], fontsize=16)

fig.savefig('coco_gcf-dpi.png', dpi=plt.gcf().dpi, bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.show()
```

And now, I finally have my plot saved exactly as I see it displayed on my screen!